# How to power-series expand determinants?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, series-expansion

Say $g$ is a matrix which is given as, $g = g_0 + xg_2 + x^2 g_4 .. +x^{d/2 -1}g_{d-2}+ x^{d/2}(g_d + h_d(\log (x)))$ where $d$ is an even number and each $g_i$ is a matrix (same dimension as $g$) and $h_d$ is another matrix.

- For such a set of arbitrary matrices, how can one power-series expand $\sqrt {\det(g)}$ in $x$?

Comment: use `MatrixPower` to evaluate `g`, then find its determinant using `Det` then take the square root of the result using `Sqrt` then use `Series` on the result.

Comment: @Nasser I want a general expression for the coefficients of $x$ in $\sqrt{det (g)}$ in terms of the matrices $g_i$ and $h_d$. I want to do this for arbitrary matrices $g_i$ and $h_d$

Comment: @user6818: I would suggest to approach the problem by first simplifying it drastically. Put g = g0 + x g1 and study the cases of 2 and 3 dimensions. Also consider the determinant itself instaed of ist Sqrt. Use Series and look at the structure of the coefficients you obtain. The results can then be cautiously generalized. MMA gives you the desired development for any concrete case. Very clumsy epressions might result.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I think it is safe to say that very clumsy expressions *will* result...

Answer (score 5):

You can use my function [MatrixD](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162063/45431) from the question [det simplification](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/161918/45431):

```
MatrixD[expr_, x__] := With[
    {old = OptionValue[SystemOptions[], "DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions"]},

    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
        SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions"->Join[old, {Det, Inverse, Tr}]];

        Unprotect[D];
        (* handle list derivatives *)
        D[h:((Det|Tr|Inverse)[m_]), {z_, n_Integer}] := Nest[D[#, Replace[z, _List :> {z}]]&, h, n];
        D[h:((Det|Tr|Inverse)[m_]), {z_List}] := D[h, #]& /@ z;
        D[h:((Det|Tr|Inverse)[m_]), z_, y___] := D[D[h, z], y];

        (* define derivatives for Det, Tr, and Inverse *)
        D[Det[m_], z:Except[_List]] := Det[m] Tr[Inverse[m] . D[m,z]];
        D[Tr[m_], z:Except[_List]] := Tr[D[m,z]];
        D[Inverse[m_], z:Except[_List]] := -Inverse[m] . D[m, z] . Inverse[m],

        D[expr, x],

        SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions"->old];
        Clear[D];
        Protect[D]
    ]
]
```

For your example:

```
g[x_] := g0 + x g2 + x^2 g4 + x^3 g6 + x^3 hd Log[x];
```

Then:

```
coeffs = Table[
    MatrixD[Sqrt[Det[g[x]]] /. Log[x]->u, {x, n}]/n! /. {x->0, u->Log[x]},
    {n, 0, 3}
];
Print @* TeXForm /@ coeffs;
```

> $\sqrt{\left| \operatorname{g0}\right| }$
>
> $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\left| \operatorname{g0}\right| } \operatorname{Tr}\left[\operatorname{g0}^{-1}.\operatorname{g2}\right]$
>
> $\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\left| \operatorname{g0}\right| } \operatorname{Tr}\left[\left(-\operatorname{g0}^{-1}.\operatorname{g2}.\operatorname{g0}^{-1}\right).\operatorname{g2}+\operatorname{g0}^{-1}.(2 \operatorname{g4})\right]+\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\left| \operatorname{g0}\right| } \operatorname{Tr}\left[\operatorname{g0}^{-1}.\operatorname{g2}\right]^2\right)$
>
> $\frac{1}{6} \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\left| \operatorname{g0}\right| } \operatorname{Tr}\left[2 \left(-\operatorname{g0}^{-1}.\operatorname{g2}.\operatorname{g0}^{-1}\right).(2 \operatorname{g4})+\left(-\left(-\operatorname{g0}^{-1}.\operatorname{g2}.\operatorname{g0}^{-1}\right).\operatorname{g2}.\operatorname{g0}^{-1}-\operatorname{g0}^{-1}.\operatorname{g2}.\left(-\operatorname{g0}^{-1}.\operatorname{g2}.\operatorname{g0}^{-1}\right)-\operatorname{g0}^{-1}.(2 \operatorname{g4}).\operatorname{g0}^{-1}\right).\operatorname{g2}+\operatorname{g0}^{-1}.(6 \operatorname{g6}+6 \operatorname{hd} \log (x))\right]+\frac{3}{4} \sqrt{\left| \operatorname{g0}\right| } \operatorname{Tr}\left[\operatorname{g0}^{-1}.\operatorname{g2}\right] \operatorname{Tr}\left[\left(-\operatorname{g0}^{-1}.\operatorname{g2}.\operatorname{g0}^{-1}\right).\operatorname{g2}+\operatorname{g0}^{-1}.(2 \operatorname{g4})\right]+\frac{1}{8} \sqrt{\left| \operatorname{g0}\right| } \operatorname{Tr}\left[\operatorname{g0}^{-1}.\operatorname{g2}\right]^3\right)$

Let's evaluate the first few terms of the series using an explicit set of matrices:

```
SeedRandom[2];
rules = Thread[{g0, g2, g4, g6, hd} -> RandomReal[1,{5,3,3}]]
```

> `{g0 -> {{0.72224, 0.109449, 0.470703}, {0.535582, 0.583178, 
>       0.293942}, {0.165154, 0.601258, 0.754218}}, 
>    g2 -> {{0.771123, 0.778574, 0.0236104}, {0.922757, 0.992454, 
>       0.350409}, {0.0450047, 0.501359, 0.633756}}, 
>    g4 -> {{0.642208, 0.389875, 0.664971}, {0.843882, 0.56904, 
>       0.398212}, {0.238652, 0.673513, 0.419507}}, 
>    g6 -> {{0.587398, 0.00833523, 0.942441}, {0.771263, 0.147503, 
>       0.964774}, {0.898747, 0.332963, 0.204548}}, 
>    hd -> {{0.839035, 0.250388, 0.238638}, {0.616616, 0.879303, 
>       0.404504}, {0.402517, 0.516192, 0.292009}}}`

And the comparison:

```
N @ CoefficientList[Series[Sqrt[Det[g[x]]] /. rules, {x, 0, 3}], x]

coeffs /. rules //Expand
```

> {0.507317, 0.663253, 0.436586, 0.0826776 + 0.572028 Log[x]}
>
> {0.507317, 0.663253, 0.436586, 0.0826776 + 0.572028 Log[x]}

Answer (score 3):

For any square matrix M which is the sum of two similar matrices M = A + B the determinant can be written as a sum of determinants as follows (example for two dimensions):

```
det(M) = det( ( A11 + B11, A12 + B12), (A21 + B21, A22 + B22) )

= det( ( A11 + 0, A12 + 0),  (A21 + B21, A22 + B22) )
+ det( ( 0 + B11, 0 + B12),  (A21 + B21, A22 + B22) )
```

and, expanding the lower row similarly,

```
= det( ( A11 + 0, A12 + 0),  (A21 + 0, A22 + 0) )
+ det( ( A11 + 0, A12 + 0),  (0 + B21, 0 + B22) )

+ det( ( 0 + B11, 0 + B12),  (A21 + 0, A22 + 0) )
+ det( ( 0 + B11, 0 + B12),  (0 + B21, 0 + B22) )

= det( ( A11, A12),  (A21, A22) )
+ det( ( A11, A12),  (B21, B22) )
+ det( ( B11, B12),  (A21, A22) )
+ det( ( B11, B12),  (B21, B22) )
```

Letting B = x C gives then the expansion

```
det(M) = 
= det( ( A11, A12),  (A21, A22) )
+ x det( ( A11, A12),  (C21, C22) )
+ x det( ( C11, C12),  (A21, A22) )
+ x^2 det( ( C11, C12),  (C21, C22) )
```

Here we recognise det(A) and det(C) but also determinants of matrices mixed between A and C, more exactly, with replacement of rows.

This procedure obviously generalizes to your problem. You might wish to write it down in MMA terms.

Regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: Dr. Wolfgang Hintze, I just read your profile.  Welcome aboard, and I hope you find this "home" to your liking.  By the way, you should read [Markdown Editing Help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) -- it'll help you make your posts look spiffy.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, yes, I do like it, thanks. I read your profile as well and found you very active in the old group. Surprisingly, we had no topic in common there ...