# det simplification

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, linear-algebra

I have a big matrix with 8 by 8 and each of element is a polynomial function with regard to w. I need to calculate det[Matrix-identitymatrix], but since the large calculation, Mathematica cannot handle it, but actually, I only need the first coefficient of w in det[Matrix-identitymatrix], so I get rid of high power: Det[QM - IdentityMatrix] // Function[y, Normal[y + O[w]^2]]. but still cannot get the result after half hour, do I have any other option? Thanks, guys!

Comment: Can you provide (code that generates) a typical matrix that we can work with? Is `w` the only parameter that is not numerical in the matrix? What are the degrees of the polynomials?

Comment: I guess you need in the first place to expand the 64 entries of your "big matrix" and keep up to the linear terms in `w` before the calculation of determinant. Try `Series` function.

Comment: Just to expand on @AlexanderZeng's comment, have you tried `Det[Map[Normal@Series[#, {w, 0, 1}] &, QM - IdentityMatrix[8], {2}]]`?

Comment: I tried the method you mentioned, it becomes a little bit better. and I'm sorry I cannot give you the code as it's a very long code, and each matrix elements comes from a system and each of them may contain thousand item and 5 other variables. in fact, I have no idea what's it looks like, I can only guess. but thanks for the idea, it's very convenient and help.

Comment: If they are so complicated, and depend on other parameters than `w`, what do you expect to gain from your calculation? What will you learn from a super complicated symbolic coefficient? What are you going to use it for? Maybe this is an XY-problem...

Comment: @ Marius Ladegård Meyer, thanks. I use this result to draw a picture with regard to other parameters. the real value is not so important than the expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could just interpolate. Alternatively, to get just constant and linear terms could do as follows.

(1) Evaluate determinant at `w->0` for constant term.

(2) Successively take derivative of each row to obtain 8 new matrices, evaluate determinant of each with `w->0`, and take sum. This gives the coefficient of the linear term.

Random example:

```
randomPoly[deg_, max_, x_] := 
 RandomInteger[{-max, max}, deg + 1].x^Range[0, deg]
randomMatrix[m_, n_, deg_, max_, x_] := 
 Table[randomPoly[deg, max, x], {m}, {n}]
SeedRandom[1111];
n = 4;
mat = randomMatrix[n, n, 3, 10, x]

(* Out[62]= {{-8 + 5 x - 3 x^2 - 8 x^3, -4 + 2 x + 4 x^2 + 2 x^3, -2 + 
   7 x - x^2 - 10 x^3, 
  9 - 6 x - 3 x^2 - 2 x^3}, {5 - 2 x + 4 x^2 + 6 x^3, 
  4 + 5 x^2 - 8 x^3, -5 + 4 x + 5 x^2 - 3 x^3, -6 - 6 x - 7 x^2 - 
   9 x^3}, {8 + 9 x + 2 x^2 + 10 x^3, 1 + 5 x + 8 x^2 - 8 x^3, 
  4 + 5 x - 2 x^2 + x^3, -9 - 10 x - 4 x^2 - 3 x^3}, {3 + 10 x, -2 + 
   4 x + x^2 + 7 x^3, 
  10 - 5 x - 3 x^2 - 10 x^3, -6 - 8 x - 6 x^2 + 7 x^3}} *)
```

First find the determinant the hard way.

```
Det[mat - IdentityMatrix[n]]

(* Out[64]= -588 + 608 x + 4765 x^2 + 2367 x^3 + 3916 x^4 - 812 x^5 - 
 21041 x^6 + 255 x^7 - 34513 x^8 + 13674 x^9 - 18497 x^10 - 
 2682 x^11 + 4336 x^12 *)
```

Constant term:

```
const = Det[mat - IdentityMatrix[n] /. x -> 0]

(* Out[68]= -588 *)
```

Linear term coefficient:

```
dmats = 
  Table[MapAt[D[#, x] &, mat - IdentityMatrix[n], j], {j, n}];
lincoeff = Total[Map[Det, dmats] /. x -> 0]

(* ut[67]= 608 *)
```

Comment: As a beginner, I'm quite confused with seed random, and could you explain it in a simple way, please? Thanks!

Comment: `SeedRandom` allows one to get "Random" results in a way that can be repeated.

Answer (score 8):

One can make use of matrix differentials, e.g. formula (42) of [The Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf):

$$\partial \left(\operatorname{det} \left(X\right) \right) = \operatorname{det} \left(X\right)  \operatorname{Tr}\left[X^{-1}.\partial X\right]$$

Using @DanielLichtblau's example:

```
m[x_] = mat - IdentityMatrix[4];
Det[m[x]]
```

> -588 + 608 x + 4765 x^2 + 2367 x^3 + 3916 x^4 - 812 x^5 - 21041 x^6 + 
>    255 x^7 - 34513 x^8 + 13674 x^9 - 18497 x^10 - 2682 x^11 + 4336 x^12

we get:

```
Det[m[0]]
Det[m[0]] Tr[Inverse[m[0]] . m'[0]]
```

> -588
>
> 608

in agreement with his answer.

**Addendum**

It is possible to define differentiation rules to allow one to compute higher order terms. The first step is to teach Mathematica special rules for derivatives of [`Det`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Det), [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr) and [`Inverse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inverse). In order to do so, we need to prevent the normal derivative rules from applying, and this can be done by including these symbols in a system differentiate option for "ExcludedFunctions". The following code does this, and also defines the needed special rules for derivatives of these symbols:

```
MatrixD[expr_, x__] := With[
    {old = OptionValue[SystemOptions[], "DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions"]},

    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
        SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions"->Join[old, {Det, Inverse, Tr}]];

        Unprotect[D];
        (* handle list derivatives *)
        D[h:((Det|Tr|Inverse)[m_]), {z_, n_Integer}] := Nest[D[#, Replace[z, _List :> {z}]]&, h, n];
        D[h:((Det|Tr|Inverse)[m_]), {z_List}] := D[h, #]& /@ z;
        D[h:((Det|Tr|Inverse)[m_]), z_, y___] := D[D[h, z], y];

        (* define derivatives for Det, Tr, and Inverse *)
        D[Det[m_], z:Except[_List]] := Det[m] Tr[Inverse[m] . D[m,z]];
        D[Tr[m_], z:Except[_List]] := Tr[D[m,z]];
        D[Inverse[m_], z:Except[_List]] := -Inverse[m] . D[m, z] . Inverse[m],

        D[expr, x],

        SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions"->old];
        Clear[D];
        Protect[D]
    ]
]
```

Let's use the same example as before. We need to use `mm[x]` instead of `m[x]` so that [`Det`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Det) doesn't evaluate to a polynomial prematurely.

```
Table[
    MatrixD[Det[mm[x]], {x, n}]/n! /. 
        x->0 /. 
        Inverse[mm[0]]->Inverse[m[0]] /. 
        mm->m,
    {n, 0, 6}
]

CoefficientList[Det[m[x]], x][[;;7]]
```

> {-588, 608, 4765, 2367, 3916, -812, -21041}
>
> {-588, 608, 4765, 2367, 3916, -812, -21041}

Comment: +1. `LinearSolve[m[0], m'[0]]` might be a more efficient (and stable on floating-point) alternative to `Inverse[m[0]].m'[0]`.